# Reaching variables in other functions

Tags: actionscript-3

Im making a game as a graduation project and have encountered a little issue. The goal of the game is to maneuver a ship and avoid asteroids as long as possible. I'm almost done but I'm now trying to solve the collision detection.

My problem is how do I reach the enemy in the loop variable so that it can check for collision with it? Here is the code:

```
  package com.asgamer.basics1
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event; 

    public class Engine extends MovieClip
    {


    private var numStars:int = 80;

    private static var enemyList:Array = new Array();

    private var ourShip:Ship;

    public function Engine() : void
    {

        ourShip = new Ship(stage);          
        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage.addChild(ourShip);


        for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), 1)
        }


        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash);



    }


    private function krash(e:Event) : void
    {
        function krash(e:Event):void
        {                   

            if (enemy.hitTestObject(ourShip)==true)
            {
                    stage.removeChild(ourShip);
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash);
            }
        }
    }

    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {

        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) == 5)
        {

            var enemy:Asteroid = new Asteroid(stage);

            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);

            enemyList.push(enemy);

            stage.addChild(enemy);



        }
    }



    private function removeEnemy(e:Event)
    {
        enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    }




}

}
```

As you can see I have a function for making enemies which is called loop, and a function for collision detection called krash. But since enemy is a variable inside loop, how can I check for collision with it in the krash function. (Sort of new to actionscript, so I dont know the terminology all to well)

Answer (score 0):

In krash you will need to check each `enemy` in `enemyList`.

example:

```
private function krash(e:Event) : void
{
    function krash(e:Event):void
    {                   
        for(var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++)
        {
            if (enemyList[i].hitTestObject(ourShip)==true)
            {
                   stage.removeChild(ourShip);
                   stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if you have a lot of enemies on the stage the program will lag a bit because you're checking for collisions with all of them every frame.

Also, I'd reccommend you add something to remove you enemies from the screen :P

```
private function removeEnemy(e:Event)
{
    enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    stage.removeChild(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have a function that removes the enemy in the asteroid class, so that shouldnt be a problem. But I added the function and I still pass right through the enemies. I'f you have the time, I would be immensely grateful if you could look it through. http://www.mediafire.com/download/l7rdn07i26njgw6/Ship+game.rar

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot about this because I thought you could work out how to use it. I downloaded your game and the problem is in the "krash" function in "engine.as". You need to remove the second line and it's closing brace.